# java need to find "parent container" to setBackground transparent

Tags: java, swing, transparency

NOT NECESSARILY A DUPLICATE QUESTION

I am trying to set my Panel to be transparent. However, my "app" is part of a larger application, and I need to find out "what" contains my Panel.

```
getRoot() gives a null pointer.
```

This works BUT makes everything transparent - is there a way to tell which is my parent container?

```
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    Frame[] Frs = JFrame.getFrames();
    int n=-1;
    for (Frame f : Frs) {
        f.setOpacity(0.55f);

}
```

I am not sure whether my parent is a frame or a panel.

Is there a way to say "what am I contained in?"

```
EDIT1
```

I am aware there are similar questions WITH answer, yet they don't appear to work for me. I tried this too:

```
Container c = SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(getClass(), this);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Container "+ c.getName());
```

and again I get a null pointer

FULL CODE

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


import javax.swing.JLabel;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;

public class HelloWorldModule extends JPanel implements WorkspaceModule{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; //change this number to something more sensible
    private JLabel lblHelloWorld;

    public HelloWorldModule() {
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(647, 623);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 840));
        this.setOpaque(true);
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        try {
            this.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(150,50,50,100));
            Container c = SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(this.getClass(), this);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Container "+ c.getName());
            //this. setBackground(new java.awt.Color(150,50,50,100));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Factory "+ e);
        }

        lblHelloWorld = new JLabel("HelloWorld");
        lblHelloWorld.setBounds(33, 53, 78, 28);
        add(lblHelloWorld);

        setModuleTitle("Hello world!");



    }

    @Override
    public JComponent getVisualComponent() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public PersistedStateHolder getPersistedState() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void loadPersistedState(PersistedStateHolder state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    protected void setModuleTitle(String title) {
        putClientProperty(WorkspaceModuleProperties.COMPONENT_TITLE, title);
    }

}
```

EDIT2

```
JButton b = new JButton();
b.setVisible(true);
b.setOpaque(true);
b.setText("PRESS");
b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Container c = SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(P.getClass(), P);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Container " + c.getName());         
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get parent panel in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415963/how-to-get-parent-panel-in-java)

Comment: @RobinGreen See edit1 please Robin

Comment: Please post your full code. It may be that `this` is the wrong object.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, you seem to trying to find your parent before its actually being added to anything.  Looking for your parent within the constructor isn't going to work, because until after the constructor returns, there is no way the component could have being added to anything, for example...

```
add(new HelloWorldModule());
```

`HelloWorldModule` MUST have being initialised/constructor BEFORE it could possible be added to anything

A better solution might be to use a `HierarchyListener` to monitor changes to the parent event or use a `PropertyChangeListener` to monitor changes to the `parent` property or you could override the `addNotify` which is called when the component is added to a container.

What you would need to do is check to see if `getParent` is `null` or not.  If not, you could us [`SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getWindowAncestor%28java.awt.Component%29) to find the parent window or [`SwingUtilities.getRootPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getRootPane%28java.awt.Component%29) to get the root pane....or what ever else you need

I might add, this stinks of bad design.  A child component should not care, nor should it try to control it's parent containers - IMHO

Comment: Yes - you might well be right about the bad design! Do you know of any other way I can make my panel transparent?

Comment: See EDIT 2. I added a button. BUT when I press button I still get a null pointer for c.